# Hide/show button inside the repeater conditionally from code-behind

Tags: vb.net, repeater, ascx

I want to show/hide 'Edit' button inside the repeater from code-behind conditionally, according to file extension column in dataset. But it takes last executed  file extension and applies to all.How to handle it ? Or should i need to take dynamically generated button  id and handle it? How ?

Code on ascx -

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProjectSubFolders" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="fileID" ClientIDMode="Static" Value='<%# Container.DataItem("FileID") %>' />
<div style="width: 15%;text-align: right;"> 
                        <asp:LinkButton OnCommand="btnEditImage_Click" CssClass="link-button" Text="Edit Image" runat="server" ID="btn_ImageEdit"  CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem("FileID")%>' />
                    </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Code on codebehind

```
Public Sub rptProjectSubFolders_ItemDataBound()
    rptProjectSubFolders.DataSource = FolderHelper.ListAttachmentFiles(Me.ucFolderControl.objFolder.intID, Me.ucFolderControl.objFolder.intProjectID, Page.User.SiteUser.intID)
    rptProjectSubFolders.DataBind()
    Dim _ds1 As DataTable = New DataTable()
    _ds1 = rptProjectSubFolders.DataSource
    If _ds1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To _ds1.Rows.Count - 1
            For Each rptitem As RepeaterItem In rptProjectSubFolders.Items
                Dim EditImageLink = CType(rptitem.FindControl("btn_ImageEdit"), LinkButton)
                Dim fileExtension As String = _ds1.Rows(i).Item("FileExtension")
                If fileExtension = "jpg" OrElse fileExtension = "png" OrElse fileExtension = "jpe " OrElse fileExtension = "bmp" Then
                    ' EditImageLink.Visible = True
                    EditImageLink.Style.Add("Display", "Block")
                Else
                    ' EditImageLink.Visible = False
                    EditImageLink.Style.Add("Display", "None")
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your code, you have ItemDataBound-event and you set DataSource in that? ItemDataBound-event is usually called internally for each item databound to the control so that you can do exactly the kind of operation you want todo (manipulate items inside the repeater based on items databound). There should be no setting datasource or loopin through rows in ItemDataBound (because it's a kinda loop to begin with).

Answer (score 2):

You mention that

> " it takes last executed file extension and applies to all"

...that's because `ItemDataBound` runs many times - once for *every* data item you give to the repeater.

Yet inside that event handler you then loop through *all* the repeater items (not just the one which is related to the current event) and apply the same change to each one in turn. So by the time you've ItemDataBound has run for every data item, then of course the only one you will see is the outcome relating to the last item, because that was the last time you looped over all the items, and it over-wrote any previous changes.

The other strange thing is that you appear to be re-binding your Repeater *inside* the ItemDataBound event of the same repeater. This makes no sense and seems like it creates a circular process. The repeater only needs to be databound once during the page request, perhaps during Page_Load, or wherever else makes sense for your application. You should move that code somewhere suitable.

If you define your `ItemDataBound` event with all the arguments, you can get the *current* repeater item and just act on the items within that...something like this:

```
Sub rptProjectSubFolders_ItemDataBound(Sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    Dim EditImageLink = CType(rptitem.FindControl("btn_ImageEdit"), LinkButton)
    Dim fileExtension As String = CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRow).Item("FileExtension")

    If fileExtension = "jpg" OrElse fileExtension = "png" OrElse fileExtension = "jpe " OrElse fileExtension = "bmp" Then
        EditImageLink.Visible = True
    Else
        EditImageLink.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritemeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx for documentation.